# Which of the two would be the most efficient way to do it?

Tags: javascript, performance

Which one should I use if I had to use one?

- With method 1, I create 1 function for each possible parameters combinaison but it's easy to call.
- With method 2, I only have 1 function but it's harder to call.

Note: In the real code, I don't do create everything in the global scope but the idea is still the same.

```
       //Method 1:
       for(var key = 0 ; key < 1000 ; key++){
            for(var i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++){
                window[key + ' ' + i] = (function(key, i) { return function() {  aFunction(key, i); } })(key, i)
            }
        }

        //then I simply do
        //window['223 111']();
```

---

```
        //Method 2:
        for(var key = 0 ; key < 1000 ; key++){
            for(var i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++){
                window[key + ' ' + i] = ['aFunction',key,i]
            }
        }
        //then i need to do 
        //window[window['223 111'][0]](window['223 111'][1],window['223 111'][2]);
```

Comment: Is your question about readability or performance?

Comment: This question belongs to Code Review.

Comment: Could you give us some details on why you want to do this? In any case I'd be much better to use your own object and not `window` to store all those variables. You are polluting the global scope with 1000 variables.

Comment: What's the point of generating **one million** functions if you still need the `key` and `i` values to access the correct function? Why do you even want to use `myFuncArray[key + ' ' + i]()` instead of `myFunc(key, i)`?

Comment: This belongs on [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/)

Comment: Why don't you simply do `aFunction(223, 111);`? Please elaborate about the purpose of that huge object (`window` or whatever). If you really needed it, filling it with arrays will definitely be cheaper than functions. Please tell us how often and in what context they would be called, otherwise the efficiency is not determinable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go for clarity and ease unless you have an actual performance issue.

I'd probably replace your first version with `.bind()`

```
for(var key = 0 ; key < 1000 ; key++){
    for(var i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++){
        window[key + ' ' + i] = aFunction.bind(window, key, i);
    }
}
```

Not available in IE8 and lower, but it can be shimmed.

---

Also, you're creating quite a few global variables. I'd suggest putting them all in a namespace object.

```
var NS = {}

for(var key = 0 ; key < 1000 ; key++){
    for(var i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++){
        NS[key + ' ' + i] = aFunction.bind(window, key, i);
    }
}

NS['223 111']();
```

Comment: Would .bind() take less memory than the method 1? Or it just makes the code clearer?

Comment: @RainingChain: Smaller and clearer code. I don't know that it'll take less memory (depends on implementation details), but it certainly shouldn't take more. It's been a while since I read the spec for `.bind()`, but I seem to recall that the original function body is shared between functions created from `.bind()`, so theoretically it should be less memory. In the past, bound functions have been a little slower in execution, but again, it's been a while since I've tested it. Either way, it wouldn't be noticeable unless you're invoking the functions many thousands of times per second.